# How to change position on scroll in tinyscrollbar on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [tinyscrollbar](https://baijs.com/tinyscrollbar/).

There is Property **contentPosition**   (Number, The position of the content relative).

I cant' figure out how to change it.

My current js is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $("#contact-page__scrollbar").length > 0 ) {
        $("#contact-page__scrollbar").tinyscrollbar( {
            axis: 'x'
        })
    }      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, found solution myself

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $("#contact-page__scrollbar").length > 0 ) {
        var $scrollbar6 = $("#contact-page__scrollbar");
        $scrollbar6.tinyscrollbar( {axis: 'x'});
        var scrollbar6 = $scrollbar6.data("plugin_tinyscrollbar");
        var anchorPosition = 92;
        scrollbar6.update(anchorPosition);
        return false;
    }      
});
```